# Assign database value to Django variable

Tags: django, database, django-models

Looking to do something like this is Django:

```
$price = mysql_query("SELECT price FROM products WHERE product = '$product'");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($price);

If $result['price'] == 1:
    do something
```

My thought was something like below but seems to be way off:

```
    item = Order.objects.get(quote_number = quotex)  
    price = item.quote_status
    headers = {
    # Already added when you pass json= but not when you pass data=
    # 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-API-KEY': '',
    }     
    
    messages.success(request, price)
    if price == 2:
```

Price == 2 does not see the number 2 where messages 2 on price var
please note this is not being used to output to a template, as I already know how to do that.

Comment: This is standard way to do it. There is nothing to be way off. Remember to try/except get method of model (ObjectDoesNotExist or/and MultipleObjectsReturned if not search by pk)

Comment: Something is off because if hard code price = 2 then it works, just can't get it to pull the value and assign to the var from the db

Comment: Is it just copy/paste error ? Your variable is Item(uppercase) then you assign from item.price(lowercase)

Comment: just fixed and change code slightly, but price == 2 is still not working, where price is correctly set as 2 as shown in messages

Comment: Show your model definition. What kind of field type is `Order.quote_status`?

Comment: here you go:  quote_status = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

Comment: this fires out number 2 in this use case and assigns to price = item.quote_status correctly, but if price = 2: then it fails on this part